# How can i combine new person and a new contribution on the same page?

Tags: contacts, contributions, registration

[image]

I want to have one page with the possibility to register a new contact that have made a contribution instead of needing to do this on 2 separate pages.

Comment: Which CMS are you using?  Is this for back-end admin use or for end-users?  What would your workflow be if an existing person makes a second contribution?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can go to the Contribution page, either incognito, or if logged in by using the "or want to do this for a different person" option at the top of the page, which takes you to the same url with cid=0 inserted (or just add this to your menu for quick access), then fill in the form same as 'they' might have.

Answer (score 1):

As a user with access to CiviCRM, you can go to the "New Contribution" form and when it says "Select Contact" you can click on "New Individual" to add someone.

[image: New Contribution]

Comment: And you can change the New Individual Profile to include the fields you want to have for that screen.